# derivation block changes time step - Simulink

Tags: simulink

[image]

I am trying to derivate a speed profile with a fixed step size of 0.005 sec, but after the derivation the time step size increases to 1 second. I have set, in the Model settings, the timestep size to be 0.05 but without any success. does anybody know how to fix this?

the result I'm expecting is a discrete signal with the same step size as the original signal

Comment: could you tell  us which solver options are you using? fixed step discrete (no continuous state) + 0.005 sec solver should do it